# REST callout to another org - unable to access custom field due to it ending with __c

Tags: apex, rest-api, custom-field, wrapper-class, namespace

I am making a callout from my org to the REST endpoint of another org in our business. This is using the standard query endpoint `/services/data/v48.0/query?q=SELECT+Fields+FROM+Contact+WHERE+...`.

While I am accessing the Contact object, there are fields being returned that I need that doesn't exist in my own Contact object, therefore I can't just use `List<Contact>`.

For this, I created what I am calling a wrapper but probably using that term incorrectly here. This would give me the basic structure of the response, along with the `records` that I am trying to access.

The problem however is that the contact object on the other org has a custom field called `Custom_Field__c`. This is a valid field for their org, and I need the value for it in the response.

```
/**
 * Contact Parent Structure Response
 */
public class ContactWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled public Integer totalSize {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public Boolean done {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public List<ContactWrapperRecords> records {get;set;} 
}

/**
 * Contact record
 */
public class ContactWrapperRecords {
    @AuraEnabled public String Name {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String Id {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String Custom_Field__c {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String Email {get; set;}
}
```

The problem I am getting when trying to define what `ContactWrapperRecords` looks like is that the field ends with `__c`, and this throws an error of `Invalid character in identifier: Custom_Field__c`.

Here is what my `AuraEnabled` APEX method looks like:

```
/**
 * Get enterprise contact records
 */
@AuraEnabled()
public static ContactWrapper getEnterpriseContacts(String contactIds) {

    // Define the case service
    HTTPRestService_EnterpriseCaseCreation caseService = new HTTPRestService_EnterpriseCaseCreation();

    // Make GET callout
    String ep = restBaseEndpoint + restQueryEndpoint;
    HttpResponse calloutResponse = caseService.makeGetCallout(namedCredentialEnterprise, ep, contactIds);
    ContactWrapper records = new ContactWrapper();

    // Check response status
    if (calloutResponse.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        records = (ContactWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(calloutResponse.getBody(), ContactWrapper.class);
    }

    // Return
    return records;
}
```

What would be the best way to access this custom field ending in `__c` that's part of the response?

I thought about being lazy and doing something like this:
`calloutResponse.getBody().replaceAll('__c','')`. but I don't feel that's the correct way to handle this and will probably bite me later on.

Suggestions on an approach?

Comment: @identigral - Not quite as I followed the same pattern of turning my JSON response into the apex code I am currently using. Since the original response contains the field ending in `__c`, its using that same value in the definition it generates which is where I am running into the problem. A field can't end in `__c`, but since it is a custom field coming from another org, thats how it is being sent.

Comment: It won't work with typed deserialization unless you replace the identifier prior to deserializing. Take a look at 'JSON attribute is a reserved word or invalid identifier' paragraph in the referenced Q&A.

Comment: Okay, so it looks like they are doing what I was going to attempt : `theJson.replace('"currency":','"currencyX":'),MyStuff.class);`. Rather than do this per field though, its probably easier to handle it like I mentioned, just removing `__c` so I can omit those from the definition. Seemed a little hacky but I suppose it will do.